# Summation of an infinite series

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

For the following series,

```
S= Sum[(e^(a*m*n))*((b^(-m)*(n/2)))),{m,1,infinity}]
```

I get the output:

```
By the geometric series test, the series converges.
```

How to get the actual value of the infinite sum?

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't look like output from Mathematica, but from Wolfram Alpha.  Mathematica does produce a result but it appears Wolfram Alpha does not.  However, Wolfram Alpha does give you a partial sum, so you can conceivably just take the limit of that partial sum to get your answer.  (Also you have an extra right parenthesis.)

Answer (score 2):

Did you actually run the code in Mathematica? You have an extra round bracket. Also `infinity` is a user variable. `Infinity` (capital `I`) is a built in Mathematica symbol:

```
S = Sum[(e^(a*m*n))*((b^(-m)*(n/2))), {m, 1, Infinity}]
```

Result:

```
-((e^(a n) n)/(2 (-b + e^(a n))))
```

I also suspect that `e` is the natural exponent. If so, use the capital `E`.